# Efficient R matrix comparison

Tags: r, performance, matrix, row

In R, I have two matrices, x and y, which both have the same number of columns, say, for example:

```
x <- matrix(runif(10*20),10,20)
y <- matrix(runif(50*20),50,20)
```

What is the **most efficient** way to create a matrix which contains the result of the following comparison. Compare each row in x to each row in y (10x50 row comparisons), return how many numbers in the row of y are smaller than the corresponding number in the row of x. Put the results in a 10x50 result matrix.

The following code works, but it is not efficient:

```
result <- matrix(NA,10,50)    
for (i in 1:10) {
      for (j in 1:50) {
        result[i,j]<- sum(x[i,]>y[j,])
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you make your [example reproducible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). The code you have provided doesn't run.

Comment: and you wanted to say " return how many numbers in the row of `x` are smaller than the corresponding number in the row of `y`", correct?

Comment: how do you know it is not efficient? what did you compare it to?

Comment: `runif(50,20)` is not a thing.

Comment: @simon wuya, can you clarify/update your question?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed your code doesn't run, but I think you mean `y <- matrix(runif(50*20),50,20)`, correct?

In that case you could use the `outer` function:

```
outer(rowSums(x), rowSums(y), function(x, y) x > y)
```

EDIT

I see what you mean, sorry, could have gotten that also with the error. I think this is going to speed up your task considerably:

```
result2 <- rowSums(x[rep(1:nrow(x), nrow(y)), ] >
     y[rep(1:nrow(y), each = nrow(x)), ]) %>% 
    matrix(nrow = nrow(x))
```

Comment: I indeed meant that, sorry, question has been edited and the code now works. Your answer returns booleans though, mine returns an integer with the number of occurences of x>y

Answer (score 1):

I guess `y <- matrix(runif(50))` and you can try to use a single loop to speed up the computation:

```
t(apply(y,1,function(u) rowSums(x<u)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on @ColonelBeauvel's answer. To speed up the computation you could use one loop instead of two and loop over the smaller matrix (in your example `x`).

```
t(apply(x, 1, function(u)colSums(u > t(y))))
```

Another important note is the fact `u < t(y)`. R compares matrices column-wise that's why it is important to transpose `y` first.

Complete example with benchmarking:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(runif(10*20),10,20)
y <- matrix(runif(50*20),50,20)

f0 <- function(x, y) {
result <- matrix(NA,10,50)
for (i in 1:10) {
      for (j in 1:50) {
        result[i,j]<- sum(x[i,]>y[j,])
      }
    }
result
}

f1 <- function(x, y)t(apply(x,1,function(u)colSums(u>t(y))))

all.equal(f0(x, y), f1(x, y))
# [1] TRUE

benchmark(f0(x, y), f1(x, y), order="relative")
#       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 2 f1(x, y)          100   0.035    1.000     0.032    0.004          0         0
# 1 f0(x, y)          100   0.253    7.229     0.252    0.000          0         0
```